# Trying to find the minimum value of a card list

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the minimum value of a card in a card list. I am using List from Generics. I am working on a card game where I have to find the lowest rank that is of the same suit as the trump suit from a player's hand. I have gone about this several different ways but I am getting no where. Firstly, I tried to loop through all the players and then loop through all the cards in a player's hand and if the card suit matches the trump suit, then I need to go through the process of finding the lowest rank. I have tried to store all the cards that match the trump suit in a list and go through the list and use the min() method to find the lowest card but it is not working because for example if I have a five of clubs and then a ten of clubs the loop finsihes where it thinks the min() card is which could be the ten of clubs even though it should be the five of clubs.
I have set up hash codes for these cards and I have find the lowest card through the hashcodes but everytime i try loop through and have it print out the lowest hashcode which is associated with the lowest rank it outputs "System32.Int[]" or something like that. Also, I have tried other ways to print it out and if the hashcode is 6 it prints "0,0,0,0,0,0". I have also tried to store the lowest cards in a list with the hashcodes but it seemes to store the index literally like [5], [6] and so forth.
I am trying to find obviously 1 card from a hand of cards but I also get the error "CardsClasses.Cards" cannot implicitly convert to "CardClasses.Card". I have tried several methods to make this work. Like boxing and unboxing objects and more but still nothing works.

At this point, I am just trying to store the one lowest card in a list of one index.

```
   public static void findLowest(List<Cards> lowest_cards)
    {

        //Cards min = lowest_cards.Min();
        Console.WriteLine(lowest_cards.Min().ToString());
        List<Cards> minCard = new List<Cards>(1);
        //minCard.Append(min);
        //Console.WriteLine(min.ToString());

        foreach (Cards lowest_card in lowest_cards)
        {
            Cards min = lowest_cards.Min();
            minCard.Append(min);
        }

    }

    private static void PlayerTurn(bool playerTurn, Player player, Table table1, Deck deckUsed)
    {
        while (playerTurn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(player.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Please press the number of the card that you would like to play.");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input.ToString(), out int choice))
            {
                if (choice > 0 && choice <= player.Hand.Count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou placed {0}", player.Hand[choice - 1]);
                    table1.PlaceCardsOnTable(player, choice);
                    player.AddCardFromDeck(deckUsed);
                    playerTurn = false;

                    Console.WriteLine(player.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Cards`  and what property in `Card` you are using to assign a comparable value.

Comment: Is [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Min<T>(Func<T,int> selector)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-min-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32)))) what you are looking for?

Comment: Show us your `Cards` class please....

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Card> cards = Card.RandomCards(12);
        var sortedCards = cards.OrderBy((c) => c.Rank);
        Console.WriteLine(sortedCards.First());
        // [Two Spades]
    }
}
```

#### Card.cs

I made up a `Card` class that holds the face and suit of a card. I have included a function to convert into a string, a property to calculate rank and static methods to create lists of cards.

```
public enum Suite
{
    Clubs = 1,
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Hearts
}

public enum Face
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King
}

public class Card
{
    public Card(Suite suite, Face face)
    {
        Suite=suite;
        Face=face;
    }

    public Suite Suite { get; }
    public Face Face { get; }

    // Put whatever way you want to rank cards
    public int Rank { get => (int)Face*4+(int)Suite; }
    // Create a string from face/suite
    public override string ToString() => $"[{Face} {Suite}]";

    public static List<Card> StandardDeck()
    {
        Face[] faces = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Face)) as Face[];
        Suite[] suits = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suite)) as Suite[];

        var deck = new List<Card>();
        foreach (var suit in suits)
        {
            foreach (var face in faces)
            {
                deck.Add(new Card(suit, face));
            }
        }
        return deck;
    }
    public static List<Card> RandomCards(int count)
    {
        List<Card> deck = Card.StandardDeck();
        deck.Sort((x, y) => rng.Next(0, 2)*2-1);

        return deck.Take(count).ToList();
    }
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();
}
```